# HTML5 Video: Displaying two different subtitles simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, subtitle

I am using the standard HTML5 video subtitle functions to display subtitles (provided in srt and vtt) in the builtin HTML5 video player.

```html
<video width="100%" height="100%" autobuffer="" controls="" preload="auto" id="media" class="media embed-responsive-item">
     <source type="video/ogg" src="podm.h264.mp4&amp;t=ogv"></source>
     <source type="video/mp4" src="podm.h264.mp4&amp;t=mp4"></source>
     <track default="" label="English" srclang="en" kind="subtitle" src="podm.h264.vtt"></track>
     <track default="" label="English" srclang="en" kind="subtitle" src="podm.h264.srt"></track>
     <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 video</p>
</video>
```

Now I need to have two different subtitles to be display simultaneously, so the second subtitle is displayed on top of the first subtitle.

(Unexpectedly) I can't find any helpful information on the web for displaying more than just one subtitle within HTML5 video. I'm pretty sure I am gonna need a custom hack for that purpose.

I am looking for advice and/or references how to implement this feature (without using nonfree/windows-only libs and player like DivX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you understand is HTML5, there are code standars, who will want to display 2srt simultaneously ??

solution :
just provide one srt that in each subtitle includes also the second subtitle as text!!

example srt script includes ENG + FR subtitles :

```
1
00:00:30,342 --> 00:00:33,082
I came from city
Je suis venu de la ville

2
00:00:33,202 --> 00:00:36,530
do you play football?
ne vous jouez au football?

3
00:00:36,650 --> 00:00:39,965
to pay rent
de payer le loyer
```

Im not sure, for linebreak, you can try to use : | or \n or \N

Answer (score 3):

With browsers' built-in `<video>` controls, you cannot select two text tracks.

To show two text tracks, e.g. first and second, you can use javascript:

```
video.textTracks[0].mode = 'showing';
video.textTracks[1].mode = 'showing';
```

It works in Firefox, partially works in Chrome, and doesn't work in Safari.

```js
function main(){
  let video = document.querySelector('#video');
  video.textTracks[0].mode = 'showing';
  video.textTracks[1].mode = 'showing';

  /* fix cue overlap for Chrome */
  if(window.chrome){
    let sheet = document.querySelector('#videoStyle').sheet;
    let rule = Array.prototype.find.call(sheet.rules, (r) => r.selectorText === 'video::-webkit-media-text-track-display');
    let observer = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
      let height = entries[0].contentRect.height;
      let controlsHeight = 72;
      let maxCueLines = 4; // TODO adjust this according to your vtt
      rule.style.setProperty('top', `calc(${Math.floor((1 - controlsHeight / height) * 100)}% - ${maxCueLines}em)`, 'important');
    });
    observer.observe(video);
  }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);
```

```html
<div>
  <strong>Showing two text tracks</strong><br/>
  Firefox: supported, built-in<br/>
  Chrome: partially supported, need trick to fix<br/>
  Safari: not supported yet<br/>
</div>

<video id="video" width="640" height="360" controls=""
    src="https://storage.googleapis.com/media-session/caminandes/short.mp4" crossorigin="anonymous" preload="metadata">
  <track kind="captions" srclang="en" src="https://static.3playmedia.com/p/files/6157318/threeplay_transcripts/18335056.vtt?project_id=10127&format_id=51&refresh=1620709875" default="" />
  <track kind="captions" srclang="en-GB" src="https://static.3playmedia.com/p/files/6157318/threeplay_transcripts/18335056.vtt?project_id=10127&format_id=51&refresh=1620709875" />
</video>

<style id="videoStyle">
video::cue {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #666666;
}
/* fix cue overlap for Chrome */
video::-webkit-media-text-track-display {
  position: relative!important;
  transform: none!important;
}
</style>
```